# weird usage of unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, return-by-reference

I'm seeing some code that uses `unique_ptr` in some weird ways, i'm not sure if it is even legal, although it seems to compile fine on g++ with `-std=c++0x`

```
#include <memory>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

typedef std::unique_ptr< std::string > str_ptr_t;

typedef boost::unordered_map< int , str_ptr_t > map_t;

str_ptr_t& get_ptr_value(map_t& map, int key)
{
   return map[key];
};

int main()
{
  map_t map;
  str_ptr_t& ref_to_value_of_0 = get_ptr_value(map, 0);
  map[0] = std::move(ref_to_value_of_0);
};
```

briefly explained, the map value type is a `unique_ptr< std::string >`. I initialise a reference to the value of key = 0. I then proceed to move the content of that reference to the same instance value, so basically the unique_ptr is being moved onto itself. This seems that to avoid creating many instances of the pointed object, it is attempted to reuse the existing entry instance if one already exists, and then add it again. In reality the assignment is hidden inside a `store` interface, and the reference is returned from a `get` interface, but the overall sequence can be summarized in the code i show above

Besides of being a bit weird, is this valid usage of `unique_ptr`?

Comment: Looks fine to me (except the last line, which does nothing). Beware however if you're on any Unix-like OS, since `_t` types are reserved by POSIX.

Comment: There are two empty statements/declarations at namespace scope. The two semicolons after the closing curlies of the two functions are wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The move assignment is defined in terms of reset and release, and so it's essentially doing this:

```
ref_to_value_of_0.reset(ref_to_value_of_0.release())
```

If you work out how this is evaluated you will find it to be a safe "no-op". It releases the owned pointer, frees a null, then sets its pointer back to original value.

I don't really understand why you are doing that though.

Comment: I think this is not equivalent, because it's a move _assignment_, not move constructor.

Comment: @SethCarnegie I know. I wrote the answer for move assignment.

Comment: But then, the move assignment op assumes they are managing two different pointers, it will give the dying one the pointer it owns, and let it deallocate it, no? Unless it is specially written to handle self-move.

Comment: @SethCarnegie work out the steps of the evaluation in your head. First it releases and sets to null, then it frees itself (which is null), then it sets back to original value.

Comment: Oh, I missed the line where you said that the standard defines it this way, that makes all the difference.

Comment: I really love this sneaky technique, easy-peasy strong exception guarantee for move-assignment.

Comment: I am not too sure about that. The `as if` calling is not binding as far as I know and just a quick way of explaining the intending semantics. In this particular case, I seem to recall an explanation by Howard Hinnant that you did not have to check for self-assignment in move constructors because the standard expects an r-value reference not to be alias (after all, how could you alias a temporary: it has no name!) so I would be very wary of such construct for now.

Comment: @MatthieuM. you don't _need_ to check for self-assignment if you implement it as if by `reset(u.release())`, it is naturally safe against self-assignment

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I know (and understand), but the question is whether the Standard *guarantees* this is safe or not. That is still shrouded in mystery.

Comment: FTR, the rule you're referring to is in [res.on.arguments] and was changed by [DR 1204](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#1204)